# How do I add tailwindcss to my Phoenix project without breaking the existing styling?

Tags: phoenix-framework, tailwind-css

Adding tailwindcss to my Phoenix project seems to have broken a lot of the styling. For example, here is a button before adding tailwindcss:

[image: Before adding Tailwind]

and here it is afterwards:

[image: After adding Tailwind]

What can I do to get the benefits of tailwind without breaking my existing styling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the native Phoenix styles break is because Tailwind comes with Preflight, which is a bunch of default styles. Preflight can conflict with whatever native styling you might have. That's why it broke in my case. I was able to solve this problem by adding:

> corePlugins: {
> preflight: false,   },

To `module.exports` in `tailwind.config.js`. This disables Preflight and lets the native Phoenix styles stay. If you don't need Preflight this is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following stop-gap solution: use the approach described in the section entitled "Using Tailwind without PostCSS" from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation.

```sh
cd assets/static
mkdir -p css
cd css
npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build -o tailwind.css
```

In whichever file contains the `<head>` tag (for example `root.html.leex`) insert this snippet:

```html
    <link href="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/css/tailwind.css") %>" rel="stylesheet">
```

I got best results by putting that above the line with

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css") %>"/>
```

Otherwise Tailwind overrides some of the styling that comes with Phoenix.